# Adding new locale to Android OS

Tags: android

I need to add a new locale to Android OS. I, with my team, will
translate all the apps provided by Android OS (e.g. Calculator) to
that language. It is based on Arabic script and is RTL. I have
reviewed how other apps are translated into Arabic on
android.googlesource.com

Android OS has already been translated into many languages. I saw that in source code where for each app a new strings.xml file is created for a new language,

for example

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calculator/+/master/res/values-ur-rPK/

I have few questions:

1. How would I make sure that this new language appears in Settings ->
   Language & Input -> Language?
2. Is it up to manufacturer to show or hide any language?
3. English is shortly written as en, Farsi is shortly written as fa.
   Similarly, the language I want to add is Sindhi and is shortly written
   as sd. Will Android know if I make folder like values-sd in res
   folder?
4. Sindhi is language spoken in India and Pakistan. Urdu is also one
   language spoken in both countries. However, the folder for Urdu was
   named as vaues-ur-rPK. I know PK means Pakistan, but I don't know what
   "r" stands for in rPK. Is there a naming conventions? Is it for right
   to left languages? Folder for Farsi was not named this way?

If there is something else I should know about, kindly let me know. I
have read a lot on https://source.android.com and have answers to some
basic questions. I am confused about the above questions.

Note: I had asked my question on android google groups for developers. One group  rejected my post from appearing in the group and in other group no one was interested in my questions. Therefore, I am asking here.

Comment: "Is it up to manufacturer to show or hide any language?" -- more accurately, it is up to the ROM author. For most devices, that is the manufacturer, though there are third-party custom ROMs (e.g., CyanogenMod). "but I don't know what "r" stands for in rPK" -- that's a region code. Basically, for an ISO 639 language of `xx_YY`, we use `-xx-rYY` when creating resources for it. You might see if books on Android internals cover your other topics.